# 'import ... =' can only be used in TypeScript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, node-modules

Error:- 
'import ... =' can only be used in TypeScript files.
'=' expected.
';' expected.
Unexpected keyword or identifier.

package.json
"type": "module"

Code--

Index.cjs

```
import msg as msg from "./tm.js"
// module imprted
// function called with integers for their sum
console.log(tm.msg(5,6))
// expected output-
// Function Imported
// 11
```

Module file--
tm.js

```
exports.msg = function (a,b) {
    console.log("Function Imported")
    return a+b;
}
```

While working with Node.js I got stuck at this error.
So, I wish anyone can help me out.

I tried Lots of things and Researched about this error.
Finally I got the solution and different Reasons why this error occurs.
So, I have shared my answer below for you to Help!

Comment: What's going on here? It's not a Question-And-Answer-On-Your-Own site (well, it can be but you posted both at the _same_ time). Is this shameless self promotion? A hack to get reputation? What is going on here?

Comment: I am actually working to hard to get solution to this problem.

Comment: So, while working I got solution in 10 mins and I thought why not post the ans. on same time. Well there is no Question or Answer for this Error, So what's wrong in it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of Error can be caused by different kinds of mistake.
Make sure that while using import statement, your file type must be module.
This can be achieved by using '.mjs' extension like tm.mjs OR
by using "type": "module" in package.json 
And for module file use '.cjs' extension
First make your file Index.js with type module or make it Index.mjs

Ans.1-
import msg as msg from "./tm.js"
Ans.- Silly mistake
Use this to get rid of most of the errors-

```
import * as tm from "./tm.cjs"
console.log(tm.msg(5,6))
```

Ans.2-

```
import {msg} from "./tm.cjs"
console.log(msg(5,6))
```

If you are using VS Code then
U may install "Flow Language Support" for ease in work.